# How can I find a specific substring in a Pandas DataFrame, and then get the text after it?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a Pandas dataframe that I am getting from an html webpage. The dataframe is ONLY 1 column and that column has no identifying name. I want to find a specific substring from within the dataframe, and then get the text immediately following that substring.

Note: there will NEVER be repeats in the substring search. 
Eg: there will NEVER be 2 instances of School 2:

The dataframe is formatted like this:

```
School 1: 1 Hour Delay
School 2: 2 Hour Delay
School 3: Closed
```

I want to be able to search for School 3: and then return the status, whether it be closed, 1 hour delay, or 2 hour delay.

My initial thought was just `if "School 3:" in df print("School 3: found")`
But I just get an error from that, I'm assuming because you can't just check for a string like that. If anyone knows how to find a substring and then get the text after it I would love to know.

Comment: What if multiple rows match this string? What would you have printed out?

Comment: @coldspeed Edited the post to explain this. There will NEVER be duplicates of the string in this table. Only ONE row will contain the string at any given time.

Comment: @coldspeed would that matter? Why not return several rows in that case?

Comment: @SpghttCd I'm just curious how OP wants their function to work. And they are actually reciprocating with helpful information so I am very tempted to write an answer

Comment: @MrShawn Okay. Next question, is it possible that _no_ row matches this condition?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes it is possible that no row matches the condition, I am handling this by having a default value, and only changing it to the status of School 3: if it is found.

The function will look for School 3: in the table and then set a string to the status text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming exactly *one* row *always* matches this condition, you can use `str.extract`:

```
df.iloc[:,0].str.extract('(?<=School 3: )(.*)', expand=False).dropna().values[0]
# 'Closed'
```

(Note: if more than one row matches this condition, only the status of the first match is returned.)

Otherwise, if it is possible nothing matches, you will need a try-except:

```
try:
    status = (df.iloc[:,0]
                .str.extract('(?<=School 3: )(.*)', expand=False)
                .dropna()
                .values[0])    
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    status = np.nan
```

Comment: I tried your first method and got an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: @MrShawn Um? Isn't that weird? `df` should be a _DataFrame_, not a list. Perhaps you meant to run this code on the variable that is actually your DataFrame...

Comment: unless I was using Pandas wrong this is the variable: df = pd.read_html(url)

Comment: @MrShawn Yes, you are almost there but not quite. For whatever reason, `read_html` returns a list. The first element of this list is your DataFrame, so do `df = pd.read_html(url)[0]`!

Comment: ah, thank you for that! I fixed that up a bit and got this new error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @MrShawn That means the substring was not found. Check and see that it actually does not exist. If it does not exist, my second code snippet will handle it appropriately.

Comment: Got it working with your second snippet, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MrShawn You're welcome. Thanks for accepting, and you can also _upvote_ the other answers as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposed the dataframe looks like

```
                   status
0  School 1: 1 Hour Delay
1  School 2: 2 Hour Delay
2        School 3: Closed
```

you could do

```
txt = 'School 3'
df.status[df.status.str.contains(txt)].str[len(txt) + 2:]   # +2 for skipping ": " after the school name
```

Result:

```
2    Closed
Name: status, dtype: object
```

---

However, IMO it would be even more clear by firstly splitting the single column which contains two informations in two:

```
df = df.status.str.split(': ', expand=True)
df.columns = ['school', 'status']

#     school        status
#0  School 1  1 Hour Delay
#1  School 2  2 Hour Delay
#2  School 3        Closed
```

then you can simply retrieve the contents of column two via boolean indexing of column one:

```
txt = 'School 3'
df.status[df.school==txt]

#2    Closed
#Name: status, dtype: object
```

Comment: However the dataframe ONLY has 1 column, so I can't get the status form a seperate column. I need to find the text "School 3:" from the column and then get the rest of the text from that row.

Comment: Yes, this dataframe has only one column, which is called `'status'` here and has the content `'School 1: 1 Hour Delay'` in its first row. I don't know how it is called in your concrete case, you did not post it.

Comment: Ah, I'll add it to the main post. The column actually has no name just data values.

Comment: So its name is `0`?

Comment: I'm not sure if Pandas / Python uses 0 as the default value for nothing, but the name is more like null

Comment: Perhaps you can simply post the result of `df.head()`? There the structure of your dataframe should be shown clearly.